# Unable to delete folders currently working on using batch file

Tags: batch-file, cmd

```
@echo off
rem setting folder variables
set "mymov=D:\Movies\My"
set "hermov=D:\Movies\Her"
set "themmov=D:\Movies\Them"
set folders=%mymov% %hermov% %themmov% 
set ext=".mp4" ".mov" ".avi" 
set test=0

for %%f in (%folders%) do (
    echo "searching in %%f"
    cd /D %%f
    for %%i in (*.*) do (
            for %%b in (%ext%) do (
            if "%%~xi"==%%b (
                set test=1
                echo "match_found_not_deleting %%f")
         )
    )
    if %test%==0 (
        echo deleting %%f
        rd /s /q %%f
          )
)
```

I am trying to delete the folders stored in `%%f` but as my batch file is processing it I get an error that it is being used in some other process. 
How can i fix it?
 Please help.[image: Error]

Answer (score 0):

Windows thinks that another application needs that folder and will not allow deletes until the other application is done using it.  Try these items to find what else is accessing your folder.

- check if you have another command window or windows explorer that is in (or under) that folder.
- Check if you have a application open that is using a file in (or under) that folder.
- Stop all the applications that are not absolutely needed.
- if that doesn't work, reboot the computer, and only start the applications you need.

Comment: I am sure that its the same batch file that i am executing caused the error. As the batch file is working on those files windows cant delete them, which is what I am doing using my batch file. Please try to optimize my code in some way that it wont happen. Thanks in advance.